# UITableView Cells not Autoresizing With Label Text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

EDIT EDIT: I started from scratch in a new project. Every storyboard outlet is identical, as is the VC code. It works, interestingly.

EDIT: hello everyone, I am giving up. Every answer is starting to become a variation on a theme, and that theme is not fixing this. Thanks for the attempt though.

In `ViewDidLoad`, I have set:
`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0`, `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

I have also, in storyboard, set: the auto-resizing constraints to the content view. [image]

the label to wrap, and the label lines to 0

Yet still, the label text is overflowing its cell.
The complete string is: "HELLO? WHAT HAPPENS IF I WRITE A LONG SENTENCE?"

[image]

Any tips?

Here is the entire view controller:
[image]
And here is the storyboard with the label selected:
[image]

after the recommended functions:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPWy6.png)
the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYceP.png)

Comment: have you given the top, left,right and bottom constraint to the label in the content view as well?
and also lines to 0 and line break to word wrap??

Comment: Yes. If you look at the first image, you'll see the constraints for the label, inside the content view. Below that, I believe I also stated that the label wraps, and the lines are set to 0.

Comment: add this delegate in your calss as well--> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

Comment: let me know if it works for you else will suggest some other solution

Comment: @blue_shoes what you trying to do ? Do you want to fix all text to cell or  auto resizable cell to content ?

Comment: That did not work, sadly. I believe that heightForRowAt is similar to "tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension". Nonetheless it was a good thought.

Comment: @SidMhatre I'm trying to make the cell's height grow automatically with the label, so that when the full string extends across multiple lines on the label, the cell grows taller to accommodate it. The problem seems to be that the label is not growing at runtime.

Comment: @blue_shoes, in Result: enter image description here, there's height constraint, remove that and it will work fine.

Comment: No, that fails to fix it. That's how it was when I started, and it's a >= constraint, not an = or <=.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the heightForRowAt indexPath..
for that you should first get the size of your text
in my case i got the size through

```
func rectForText(text: String, font: UIFont, maxSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
{
    let attrString = NSAttributedString.init(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:font])
    let rect = attrString.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
    let size = CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)//(, )
    return size
}
```

and set the height of cell according to your text, in **my case**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var totalHeight : CGFloat = 0
    let str = yourString
    let size : CGSize = rectForText(text: str, font:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0) , maxSize : CGSize(width: 200 * (SCREEN_WIDTH / 320), height: 20000) )
    totalHeight = size.height
    return CGFloat(totalHeight)
}
```

might be work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding constraints to the label that's in the content view.

E.g.: 
left - 8 pts
top - 8 pts
right - 8 pts
bottom - 8 pts

Now it should stay within the cell.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is that multiple words - which would cross into an extra line - are being cut off. I have edited my post to include the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to automatically adjust cell height to its content.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Hi Sid, Ishika recommended that above, but when I added this function inside the class next to the other delegate functions, it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the screenshot of my output. For the label, you should give all the four constraints(top:5, bottom:5, left:5, right:5) and you have to change the heights of the label's priority to 750 & set the hugging and resistance priority to 1000. Then you have to change the number of lines to 0 in storyboard

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 250

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the thoughtfulness of your reply - I have implemented this, with the functions next to the other delegate tableView functions - but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did u change the priorities?

Comment: Yes, I made the hugging and resistance priorities 1000, and added a height constraint of >=10 for the label which I set to 750. I have kept the other 4 constraints for top/bottom/trailing/leading, all 10, and the lines are 0. I am quite stumped.

Comment: I'll post it again with the added functions.

Comment: @blue_shoes:Hi,I m facing the same issue.Is this resolved from your end?